# Periodic Green's function for Laplacian in $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, greens-function

The periodic Green's function $G^p$ for Laplacian $\Delta$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ is defined by lattice sum:
$$G^p(x)=-\sum_{n\in \mathbb{Z}^3-\{0\}}\frac{e^{2\pi i n\cdot x}}{4\pi^2|n|^2}$$
and it is well known that the fundamental solution $G$ for $\Delta$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ is
$$G(x)=-\frac{1}{4\pi |x|}$$

> **Problem** The function
>   $$R=G^p-G$$
>   belongs in $C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^3)$, and has its Taylor expansion:
>   $$R(x)=R(0)-\frac{1}{6}|x|^2+O(|x|^4)$$

**My attempt** By writing
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
G^p(x)=\ & -\sum_{n\in \mathbb{Z}^3-\{0\}}\frac{e^{2\pi i n\cdot x}}{4\pi^2|n|^2}=
-\frac{1}{4\pi^2} \sum_{n\in \mathbb{Z}^3-\{0\}}\frac{\cos 2\pi n_1x_1\cos 2\pi n_2x_2\cos 2\pi n_3x_3}{n_1^2+n_2^2+n_3^2} \\
=\ &-\frac{2}{\pi^2}\sum_{n_1\geq 1}\cos 2\pi n_1x_1\sum_{n_2\geq 1}\cos 2\pi n_2x_2
\sum_{n_3\geq 1}\frac{\cos 2\pi n_3x_3}{n_1^2+n_2^2+n_3^2} \\
&\ -\frac{1}{\pi^2}\sum_{n_1\geq 1}\cos 2\pi n_1x_1\sum_{n_2\geq 1}
\frac{\cos 2\pi n_2x_2}{n_1^2+n_2^2}-\frac{1}{2\pi^2} \sum_{n_3\geq 1} \frac{\cos 2\pi n_3x_3}{n_3^2} \\
&\ -\frac{1}{\pi^2}\sum_{n_1\geq 1}\cos 2\pi n_1x_1\sum_{n_3\geq 1}
\frac{\cos 2\pi n_3x_3}{n_1^2+n_3^2}-\frac{1}{2\pi^2} \sum_{n_2\geq 1} \frac{\cos 2\pi n_2x_2}{n_2^2} \\
&\ -\frac{1}{\pi^2}\sum_{n_2\geq 1}\cos 2\pi n_2x_2\sum_{n_3\geq 1}
\frac{\cos 2\pi n_3x_3}{n_2^2+n_3^2}-\frac{1}{2\pi^2} \sum_{n_1\geq 1} \frac{\cos 2\pi n_1x_1}{n_1^2} \\
:=\ &\Lambda(x)+\Theta_1(x)+\Theta_2(x)+\Theta_3(x)
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

By invoking the summation identities:
\begin{equation}
\sum_{n_2\geq 1}\frac{\cos 2\pi n_2 x_2}{n_1^2+n_2^2}=\left\{
\begin{aligned}
& -\frac{1}{2n_1^2}+\frac{\pi}{2n_1}\frac{\cosh \pi(2x_2-1)n_1}{\sinh \pi n_1} &n_1\neq 0\\
&\frac{\pi^2}{6}-\pi^2x_2+\pi^2x_2^2 & n_1=0
\end{aligned}\right.
\end{equation}
$$\sum_{n_1\geq 1}\frac{\cos 2\pi n_1x_1}{n_1}e^{-2\pi n_1x_2}=\pi x_2-\log 2-\frac{1}{2}\log (\sinh^2 \pi x_2 +\sin^2\pi x_1)$$
I have calculated 
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\Theta_1(x)&:=-\frac{1}{\pi^2}\sum_{n_1\geq 1}\cos 2\pi n_1x_1\sum_{n_2\geq 1}
\frac{\cos 2\pi n_2x_2}{n_1^2+n_2^2}-\frac{1}{2\pi^2} \sum_{n_3\geq 1} \frac{\cos 2\pi n_3x_3}{n_3^2} \\
&=\frac{1}{12}+\frac{\log 2}{2\pi}-\frac{x_1+x_2}{2}+\frac{x_1^2}{4}
+\frac{\log (\sinh^2 \pi x_2 +\sin^2\pi x_1)}{8\pi}+r_1(x)
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
where $r_1(x)\in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^3)$ and $r_1(x)=O(|x|^4)$. 
therefore, we have 
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\Theta_1(x)&+\Theta_2(x)+\Theta_3(x)= \frac{1}{4}+\frac{3\log 2}{2\pi}-(x_1+x_2+x_3)+\frac{x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2}{4}+r_1(x)+r_2(x)+r_3(x) \\
&+\frac{\log (\sinh^2 \pi x_2 +\sin^2\pi x_1)+\log (\sinh^2 \pi x_3 +\sin^2\pi x_1)+\log (\sinh^2 \pi x_3 +\sin^2\pi x_2)}{8\pi}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
where $r_1(x)+r_2(x)+r_3(x)=O(|x|^4) $ and belongs to $C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^3)$.

**My question**

1. How to estimate
   $$\frac{\log (\sinh^2 \pi x_2 +\sin^2\pi x_1)+\log (\sinh^2 \pi x_3 +\sin^2\pi x_1)+\log (\sinh^2 \pi x_3 +\sin^2\pi x_2)}{8\pi}$$
2. How to deal with $\Lambda(x)$ term.

Any help will be appreciated.