# Summation for $\sum_{n_1\geq 1}\sum_{n_2\geq 1}\sum_{n_3\geq 1} \frac{\cos 2\pi n_1x_1\cos 2\pi n_2x_2\cos 2\pi n_3x_3}{n_1^2+n_2^2+n_3^2} $

Tags: calculus, summation

> This question is closely related to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3682628/periodic-greens-function-for-laplacian-in-mathbbr3) I posted before, but I will state it concisely. In fact, I want to decompose that
>   $$\sum_{n_1\geq 1}\sum_{n_2\geq 1}\sum_{n_3\geq 1} \frac{\cos 2\pi n_1x_1\cos 2\pi n_2x_2\cos 2\pi n_3x_3}{n_1^2+n_2^2+n_3^2} =F(x_1,x_2,x_3)+R(x_1,x_2,x_3)$$
>   where $F(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ is a combination of some elementary functions, and $R(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ is a smooth function, i.e. $C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^3)$ function.

By invoking \begin{equation}
\sum_{n_2\geq 1}\frac{\cos 2\pi n_2 x_2}{n_1^2+n_2^2}=\left\{
\begin{aligned}
& -\frac{1}{2n_1^2}+\frac{\pi}{2n_1}\frac{\cosh \pi(2x_2-1)n_1}{\sinh \pi n_1} &n_1\neq 0\\
&\frac{\pi^2}{6}-\pi^2x_2+\pi^2x_2^2 & n_1=0
\end{aligned}\right.
\end{equation}
$$\sum_{n_1\geq 1}\frac{\cos 2\pi n_1x_1}{n_1}e^{-2\pi n_1x_2}=\pi x_2-\log 2-\frac{1}{2}\log (\sinh^2 \pi x_2 +\sin^2\pi x_1)$$
the first identity is proved by contour integral, i.e.
$$\sum_{n_2\geq 1}\frac{\cos 2\pi n_2 x_2}{n_1^2+n_2^2}=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n_2 \in \mathbb{Z}}\frac{\cos 2\pi n_2 x_2}{n_1^2+n_2^2}-\frac{1}{n_1^2}$$
and by residue theorem
$$\sum_{n_2 \in \mathbb{Z}}\frac{\cos 2\pi n_2 x_2}{2\pi i(n_1^2+n_2^2)}+\mathcal{Re}\left[\mbox{residue of }\frac{e^{i2\pi x_2z}}{(n_1^2+z^2)(e^{i2\pi z}-1)} \mbox{ at zeros of }n_1^2+z^2 \right]=\int_{C_n} \frac{e^{i2\pi x_2z}}{(n_1^2+z^2)(e^{i2\pi z}-1)}dz \rightarrow 0$$
the second identity is simply the Taylor expansion of $\log(1+z)$.

Now we calculate
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\sum_{n_1\geq 1}\cos 2\pi n_1x_1&\sum_{n_2\geq 1}\cos 2\pi n_2x_2
\sum_{n_3\geq 1}\frac{\cos 2\pi n_3x_3}{n_1^2+n_2^2+n_3^2} \\
=\ &-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n_1\geq 1}\cos 2\pi n_1x_1\sum_{n_2\geq 1}\frac{\cos 2\pi n_2x_2}{n_1^2+n_2^2} \\
&\ +\frac{\pi}{2} \sum_{n_1\geq 1}\cos 2\pi n_1x_1\sum_{n_2\geq 1}\frac{\cos2\pi n_2x_2}{\sqrt{n_1^2+n_2^2}}\frac{\cosh \pi(2x_3-1)\sqrt{n_1^2+n_2^2}}{\sinh \pi \sqrt{n_1^2+n_2^2}}  \\
=\ & G_1+\frac{\pi}{2}G_2
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
$G_1$ is easily handled. Now calculate $G_2$:
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\sum_{n_1\geq 1}&\cos 2\pi n_1x_1\sum_{n_2\geq 1}\frac{\cos2\pi n_2x_2}{\sqrt{n_1^2+n_2^2}}\frac{\cosh \pi(2x_3-1)\sqrt{n_1^2+n_2^2}}{\sinh \pi \sqrt{n_1^2+n_2^2}}  \\
=\ &\sum_{n_1\geq 1}\cos 2\pi n_1x_1\sum_{n_2\geq 1}\frac{\cos2\pi n_2x_2}{\sqrt{n_1^2+n_2^2}}\left(\frac{\cosh \pi(2x_3-1)\sqrt{n_1^2+n_2^2}}{\sinh \pi \sqrt{n_1^2+n_2^2}}-e^{-2\pi \sqrt{n_1^2+n_2^2}x_3} \right) \\
&+\sum_{n_1\geq 1}\cos 2\pi n_1x_1\sum_{n_2\geq 1}\frac{\cos2\pi n_2x_2}{\sqrt{n_1^2+n_2^2}}e^{-2\pi \sqrt{n_1^2+n_2^2}x_3}  \\
=\ &G_3+G_4
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
the terms in $G_3$ exponential decays, so $G_3$ is smooth. Now **my question is** how to calculate $G_4$? 
$$G_4=\sum_{n_1\geq 1}\cos 2\pi n_1x_1\sum_{n_2\geq 1}\frac{\cos2\pi n_2x_2}{\sqrt{n_1^2+n_2^2}}e^{-2\pi \sqrt{n_1^2+n_2^2}x_3}$$